# parsing a text file where each record spans more than 1 line

Tags: parsing, concatenation, field, multiline

I need to parse a text file that contains hundreds of records that span more than 1 line each. I'm new to Python and have been trying to do this with grep and awk in several complex ways but no luck yet.
The file contains records that look like this:

**409547095517 911033 00:47:41 C44 00:47:46 D44 00:47:53 00:47:55 
 (555) 555-1212   00:47    10/31      100        Main Street - NW

                 Some_City   TX 323 WRLS METRO PCS

                    P# 122-5217 ALT# 555-555-1212    LEC:MPCSI  WIRELESS CALL  Q
UERY CALLER FOR LOCATION  QUERY CALLER FOR PHONE #***

Really I can do all I need to if I could just get these multi-line records condensed to 1 line per record. Each record will always begin with "40" or I could let 9110 indicate start as these will always be there and are unqiue providing 40 is at begining of line. I used a HEX editer and found that I could remove all line feeds (hex 0D0A) but this is not better than manually editing the files and programaticaly I'd need to not remove the last one per record. Some records will be only 2 lines but most will be 5 like this one.

Is there a way python or otherwise to concatonate the lines that make up a record into one line where 40 or maybe better choice where 9110 indicates the start of the record?

Any ideas or pointers will be much appreciated. I've got python and a good IDE and I'm good with grep and find but learning awk (don't laugh)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk will do it.  You need to identify  The line that starts a record.  In this case it is `409547095517`
So let's assume that to be safe if a line starts with 8 numbers it is the start of a record.

```
awk ' NR> 1 && /^[0-9]{8}/ { printf("\n") }  
      {printf("%s", $0) } 
       END{ printf("\n") }'  filename > newfilename
```

Change the `{8}` to any number that works for you.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm running windows and using Gawk to try and make this work but I've tried running this in whole and in parts to understand it. Even reading the "http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html" but still not getting it. I'll keep trying. Thanks though, I'll study this...

Comment: NR> 1 && /^[0-9]{8}/   is: if number of records read is greater than one and the line starts with a bunch of numbers (8), print a newline.

Comment: Otherwise  print every record on the same line of the new file.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I've loaded up a Linux VM to try and figure it out. The GAWK on windows keeps failing based on invalid char '  It's going to take some fiddling around with it. This is good practice. Thanks for the code to look at.

Comment: Wow that took way too long to figure out. But your advice Jim was very helpful. I'm using Gawk in Windows and the way I got the desired output was to use the following one liner that is a slight modification from your suggestion:  awk "/^4/ { printf(\"\r\n\") } { printf(\"%s\", $0) } END{ printf(\"\r\n\") } " test2.txt > test2Out.txt

Comment: It seems the trick was that I needed to \ escape the quotes for the new line characters because of Windows and also because of Windows I had to use the new line char of \r\n in stead of \n. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I was also pleased to find that I could get both lines that begin with the 40NPANNXDNDN phone numbers but also preserve the new line for those calls where the caller ID could not be decoded and the result was ?????????? so the finished one liner that does the job for me is: `awk "/^4|^?/ { printf(\"\r\n\") } { printf(\"%s\", $0) } END{ printf(\"\r\n\") } " test2.txt`

Comment: Consider reading this awk tutorial: http://www.vectorsite.net/tsawk.html  There are 3 chapters.